# Seeking in AAC streams on Android

Tags: android, media-player, aac, seek

I'm getting an AAC stream from a HTTP server and using that as the datasource for the `MediaPlayer` in Android.
It plays perfectly fine, but when I try to execute `mediaPlayer.seekTo(int position)` I get the following errors about a million times:
`WARN/AACDecoder(13889): AAC decoder returned error -1, substituting silence

 WARN/AACDecoder(13889): AAC decoder returned error 10, substituting silence

 WARN/AACDecoder(13889): AAC decoder returned error 1, substituting silence`

This error happens on Android 2.2 but it does not seem to work on earlier versions either. 
Support for seeking is a must in my application, and I would like it to work for Android 1.5 - 2.2.

Is there any good solution on how to seek in AAC streams?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot seek a served stream. How could the server handle this?

Even if you save the bytes, raw AAC streams are non-seekable (they contain no seek information). Some media players get around this by parsing the whole file and indexing it on the fly every time they load it. A better solution is to repackage the stream into a container, like MP4. Here's an example using [MP4Box](http://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/mp4box/):

```
MP4Box -add raw_stream.aac -new output_file.mp4
```