# PCM -> AAC (Encoder) -> PCM(Decoder) in real-time with correct optimization

Tags: android, pcm, aac, android-mediacodec, audiorecord

I'm trying to implement

```
AudioRecord (MIC) ->

PCM -> AAC Encoder
AAC -> PCM Decode

-> AudioTrack??  (SPEAKER)
```

with `MediaCodec` on Android 4.1+ (API16).

Firstly, I successfully (but not sure correctly optimized) implemented `PCM -> AAC Encoder` by  `MediaCodec` as intended as below

```
private boolean setEncoder(int rate)
{
    encoder = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType("audio/mp4a-latm");
    MediaFormat format = new MediaFormat();
    format.setString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME, "audio/mp4a-latm");
    format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT, 1);
    format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_SAMPLE_RATE, 44100);
    format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 64 * 1024);//AAC-HE 64kbps
    format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_AAC_PROFILE, MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel.AACObjectHE);
    encoder.configure(format, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
    return true;
}
```

**INPUT: PCM Bitrate = 44100(Hz) x 16(bit) x 1(Monoral) =  705600 bit/s**

**OUTPUT: AAC-HE Bitrate = 64 x 1024(bit) = 65536 bit/s**

**So, the data size is approximately compressed `x11`** ,and I confirmed this working by observing a log

- AudioRecoder﹕ 4096 bytes read
- AudioEncoder﹕ 369 bytes encoded

the data size is approximately compressed `x11`, so far so good.

Now, I have a UDP server to receive the encoded data, then decode it.

The decoder profile is set as follows:

```
private boolean setDecoder(int rate)
{
    decoder = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType("audio/mp4a-latm");
    MediaFormat format = new MediaFormat();
    format.setString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME, "audio/mp4a-latm");
    format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT, 1);
    format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_SAMPLE_RATE, 44100);
    format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 64 * 1024);//AAC-HE 64kbps
    format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_AAC_PROFILE, MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel.AACObjectHE);
    decoder.configure(format, null, null, 0);

    return true;
}
```

Since UDPserver packet buffer size is `1024`

- UDPserver   ﹕ 1024 bytes received

and since this is the compressed AAC data, I would expect the decoding size will be

approximately 1024 `x11`, however the actual result is

- AudioDecoder﹕ 8192 bytes decoded

It's approximately `x8`, and I feel something wrong.

The decoder code is as follows:

```
    IOudpPlayer = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            SocketAddress sockAddress;
            String address;

            int len = 1024;
            byte[] buffer2 = new byte[len];
            DatagramPacket packet;

            byte[] data;

            ByteBuffer[] inputBuffers;
            ByteBuffer[] outputBuffers;

            ByteBuffer inputBuffer;
            ByteBuffer outputBuffer;

            MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufferInfo;
            int inputBufferIndex;
            int outputBufferIndex;
            byte[] outData;
            try
            {
                decoder.start();
                isPlaying = true;
                while (isPlaying)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer2, len);
                        ds.receive(packet);

                        sockAddress = packet.getSocketAddress();
                        address = sockAddress.toString();

                        Log.d("UDP Receiver"," received !!! from " + address);

                        data = new byte[packet.getLength()];
                        System.arraycopy(packet.getData(), packet.getOffset(), data, 0, packet.getLength());

                        Log.d("UDP Receiver",  data.length + " bytes received");

                        //===========
                        inputBuffers = decoder.getInputBuffers();
                        outputBuffers = decoder.getOutputBuffers();
                        inputBufferIndex = decoder.dequeueInputBuffer(-1);
                        if (inputBufferIndex >= 0)
                        {
                            inputBuffer = inputBuffers[inputBufferIndex];
                            inputBuffer.clear();

                            inputBuffer.put(data);

                            decoder.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, 0, data.length, 0, 0);
                        }

                        bufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
                        outputBufferIndex = decoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, 0);

                        while (outputBufferIndex >= 0)
                        {
                            outputBuffer = outputBuffers[outputBufferIndex];

                            outputBuffer.position(bufferInfo.offset);
                            outputBuffer.limit(bufferInfo.offset + bufferInfo.size);

                            outData = new byte[bufferInfo.size];
                            outputBuffer.get(outData);

                            Log.d("AudioDecoder", outData.length + " bytes decoded");

                            decoder.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferIndex, false);
                            outputBufferIndex = decoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, 0);

                        }



                        //===========

                    }
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                    }
                }

                decoder.stop();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
        }
    });
```

the full code:

https://gist.github.com/kenokabe/9029256

also need Permission:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"></uses-permission>
```

---

A member [fadden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/294248/fadden) who works for Google told me

Looks like I'm not setting position & limit on the output buffer.

I have read 
[VP8 Encoding Nexus 5 returns empty/0-Frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21626156/vp8-encoding-nexus-5-returns-empty-0-frames/21630351#21630351) , but not sure how to implement correctly.

---

**UPDATE: I sort of understood where to modify for**

> Looks like I'm not setting position & limit on the output buffer.

**, so add 2 lines within the while loop of Encoder and Decoder as follows:**

```
 outputBuffer.position(bufferInfo.offset);
 outputBuffer.limit(bufferInfo.offset + bufferInfo.size);
```

https://gist.github.com/kenokabe/9029256/revisions

However the result is the same.

**and now, I think, the errors:
 `W/SoftAAC2﹕ AAC decoder returned error 16388, substituting silence.` indicates this decoder fails completely from the first. It's again `the data is not seekable` issue.  [Seeking in AAC streams on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933387/seeking-in-aac-streams-on-android) It's very disappointing if the AAC decoder cannot handle the streaming data in this way but only with adding some header.**

---

**UPDATE2: UDP receiver did wrong, so modified**

https://gist.github.com/kenokabe/9029256

Now, the error

**`W/SoftAAC2﹕ AAC decoder returned error 16388, substituting silence.`
disappeared!!**

So, it indicates the decoder works without an error, at least,

however, this is the log of 1 cycle:

```
D/AudioRecoder﹕ 4096 bytes read
D/AudioEncoder﹕ 360 bytes encoded
D/UDP Receiver﹕ received !!! from /127.0.0.1:39000
D/UDP Receiver﹕ 360 bytes received
D/AudioDecoder﹕ 8192 bytes decoded
```

PCM(4096)->AACencoded(360)->UDP-AAC(360)->(supposed to be )PCM(8192)

The final result is about 2x size of the original PCM, something is still wrong.

---

So my Question here would be

1. Can you properly optimize my sample code to work correctly?
2. Is it a right way to use `AudioTrack` API to play the decoded PCM raw data on the fly, and can you show me the proper way to do that? A example code is appreciated.

Thank you.

PS. My project targets on Android4.1+(API16), I've read things are easier on API18(Andeoid 4.3+), but for obvious compatibility reasons, unfortunately, I have to skip MediaMuxer etc. here...

Comment: I'm no expert in this area but I would assume there is extra header info control data in each packet making the raw payload being smaller than 1024 so 8192 may actually be reasonable.

Comment: what's more interesting is what does the audio sound like? Is it playable after compression? Is it playable after decompression? Attempting playback is a good way to determine if compression/decompression is actually working.

Comment: Probably, `MediaPlayer` needs the header for the container of audio data, but I just decode to PCM on the fly and try to play it. Thanks Cliff.

Comment: It's basically VoiceChat app. As I mention here, MIC -> AudioRecord->Encode from rawPCM to AAC -> UDP -> Decode to rawPCM -> Speaker

Comment: interesting, I've used speex for compression (which is built for voice data) but I don't recall getting those types of results. I have examples of using speex for compression and decompression but have not taken it through UDP.

Comment: Yeah, one of the important issue here is to use Codecs primarily supported by the Hardware in this case Android. speex is probably not supported by hardware accelerated encode/decode.

Comment: https://github.com/Audioboo/audioboo-android/blob/master/src/fm/audioboo/application/FLACPlayer.java  good sample app at doing sophisticated things way down the media api stack in android.  see "audiotrack" in the linked class

Comment: Looking a little deeper in your code and I see no evidence of transfer control. UDP is unreliable and unordered meaning you're packets will not all arrive in the order sent and some will be dropped. I see you're sending the packets but how are you ordering them on the receiving side? I would try something simple like including an index in each packet (as the first 8 bytes or something) and reading it back on the client side while discarding the packets that are older than the latest one received.

Comment: In VOIP, I think it's common to use UDP instead of TCP. In my case, since the media format is predetermined, I just use bare UDP, but it's rather common to use RTP on top of UDP. I am not so sure how the unordered packets affects the decoding audio result, but I've been thinking not a big issue, however, if it's a big deal, I probably need some logic as you mentioned.

Comment: I've tried running your activity on my Galaxy Nexus 4.3 and I get a bunch of error codes from the decoder: 02-18 07:34:31.297  13286-13400/? W/SoftAAC2﹕ AAC decoder returned error 16388, substituting silence. I also get 16390 and 16391 codes. Not sure what they mean but I'll look them up.

Comment: Thanks Cliff, yeah, I notice the SoftAAC2 error, too, and I don't know what this is.

Comment: I think the errors - SoftAAC2 error indicates this decoder fails completely from the first. It's again `the data is not seekable` issue.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933387/seeking-in-aac-streams-on-android It's very disappointing if the AAC decoder cannot handle the streaming data in this way but only with adding some header. I edit my Question.

Comment: Apologies for answering for non-working code. FWIW, here's what I will be working on in the next day or so: https://gist.github.com/cliff76/83f274a4788ffd84ab4c I'm very interested in seeing your example actually work.

Comment: That is fine. Thanks for your participation and contribution here, Cliff. Now, I think the fundamental problem here is the AAC decoder error: 13286-13400. `substituting silence` probably means, `the decoding fails, so returns 00 sequences`.

Comment: AAC decoder error gone away, https://gist.github.com/kenokabe/9029256 , but the decoded size should be wrong, it's 2x of the original one. I edited my Q.

Comment: Cliff, check https://gist.github.com/kenokabe/9029256 and run the code on your devices please.
I tried to play with my emulator mic and speaker, and actually, it **slightly** worked, so the decoding process works at least.

**slightly** means, the latency is about 10 seconds, and sound quality is horrible. I test this on Genymotion emulator, and don't know how this kind of emulator affect this, and I would like to know the result on the real device.

Comment: +400 rep bounty? That's more than twice your remaining rep. There should be a badge for that.

Comment: Was this ever solved?

Answer (score 11):

After testing this is what I came up with from modifying your code:

```
 package com.example.app;

    import android.app.Activity;

    import android.media.AudioManager;
    import android.media.MediaCodecInfo;
    import android.media.MediaFormat;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    import android.media.AudioFormat;
    import android.media.AudioRecord;
    import android.media.AudioTrack;
    import android.media.MediaCodec;

    import android.media.MediaRecorder.AudioSource;

    import android.util.Log;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.DatagramPacket;
    import java.net.DatagramSocket;
    import java.net.InetAddress;
    import java.net.SocketAddress;
    import java.net.SocketException;
    import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity
    {
        private AudioRecord recorder;
        private AudioTrack player;

        private MediaCodec encoder;
        private MediaCodec decoder;

        private short audioFormat = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
        private short channelConfig = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;

        private int bufferSize;
        private boolean isRecording;
        private boolean isPlaying;

        private Thread IOrecorder;

        private Thread IOudpPlayer;


        private DatagramSocket ds;
        private final int localPort = 39000;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            IOrecorder = new Thread(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    int read;
                    byte[] buffer1 = new byte[bufferSize];

                    ByteBuffer[] inputBuffers;
                    ByteBuffer[] outputBuffers;

                    ByteBuffer inputBuffer;
                    ByteBuffer outputBuffer;

                    MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufferInfo;
                    int inputBufferIndex;
                    int outputBufferIndex;

                    byte[] outData;

                    DatagramPacket packet;
                    try
                    {
                        encoder.start();
                        recorder.startRecording();
                        isRecording = true;
                        while (isRecording)
                        {
                            read = recorder.read(buffer1, 0, bufferSize);
                           // Log.d("AudioRecoder", read + " bytes read");
                            //------------------------

                            inputBuffers = encoder.getInputBuffers();
                            outputBuffers = encoder.getOutputBuffers();
                            inputBufferIndex = encoder.dequeueInputBuffer(-1);
                            if (inputBufferIndex >= 0)
                            {
                                inputBuffer = inputBuffers[inputBufferIndex];
                                inputBuffer.clear();

                                inputBuffer.put(buffer1);

                                encoder.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, 0, buffer1.length, 0, 0);
                            }

                            bufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
                            outputBufferIndex = encoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, 0);



                            while (outputBufferIndex >= 0)
                            {
                                outputBuffer = outputBuffers[outputBufferIndex];

                                outputBuffer.position(bufferInfo.offset);
                                outputBuffer.limit(bufferInfo.offset + bufferInfo.size);

                                outData = new byte[bufferInfo.size];
                                outputBuffer.get(outData);


                               // Log.d("AudioEncoder ", outData.length + " bytes encoded");
                                //-------------
                                packet = new DatagramPacket(outData, outData.length,
                                        InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"), localPort);
                                ds.send(packet);
                                //------------

                                encoder.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferIndex, false);
                                outputBufferIndex = encoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, 0);

                            }
                            // ----------------------;

                        }
                        encoder.stop();
                        recorder.stop();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });



            IOudpPlayer = new Thread(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    SocketAddress sockAddress;
                    String address;

                    int len = 2048
                    byte[] buffer2 = new byte[len];
                    DatagramPacket packet;

                    byte[] data;

                    ByteBuffer[] inputBuffers;
                    ByteBuffer[] outputBuffers;

                    ByteBuffer inputBuffer;
                    ByteBuffer outputBuffer;

                    MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufferInfo;
                    int inputBufferIndex;
                    int outputBufferIndex;
                    byte[] outData;
                    try
                    {
                        player.play();
                        decoder.start();
                        isPlaying = true;
                        while (isPlaying)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer2, len);
                                ds.receive(packet);

                                sockAddress = packet.getSocketAddress();
                                address = sockAddress.toString();

                             //   Log.d("UDP Receiver"," received !!! from " + address);

                                data = new byte[packet.getLength()];
                                System.arraycopy(packet.getData(), packet.getOffset(), data, 0, packet.getLength());

                               // Log.d("UDP Receiver",  data.length + " bytes received");

                                //===========
                                inputBuffers = decoder.getInputBuffers();
                                outputBuffers = decoder.getOutputBuffers();
                                inputBufferIndex = decoder.dequeueInputBuffer(-1);
                                if (inputBufferIndex >= 0)
                                {
                                    inputBuffer = inputBuffers[inputBufferIndex];
                                    inputBuffer.clear();

                                    inputBuffer.put(data);

                                    decoder.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, 0, data.length, 0, 0);
                                }

                                bufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
                                outputBufferIndex = decoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, 0);

                                while (outputBufferIndex >= 0)
                                {
                                    outputBuffer = outputBuffers[outputBufferIndex];

                                    outputBuffer.position(bufferInfo.offset);
                                    outputBuffer.limit(bufferInfo.offset + bufferInfo.size);

                                    outData = new byte[bufferInfo.size];
                                    outputBuffer.get(outData);

                                  //  Log.d("AudioDecoder", outData.length + " bytes decoded");

                                    player.write(outData, 0, outData.length);

                                    decoder.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferIndex, false);
                                    outputBufferIndex = decoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, 0..
```

Comment: Thanks, can you please add description for where and how you did modify.

Comment: It looks like the source in the answer is truncated. Could you provide detail on what needed to be changed and where?

Comment: the code above still doesn't respect the return value of `MediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer`. It should check whether it returns any of the special status codes, and react accordingly (e.g. get new buffers or change the format). Without this, the code is guaranteed to fail on some devices.

Comment: its giving `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` on `encoder.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, 0, buffer1.length, 0, 0);` . What is the solution?

Answer (score 6):

Self Answer, here's my best effort so far

```
package com.example.app;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaCodecInfo;
import android.media.MediaFormat;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.AudioTrack;
import android.media.MediaCodec;

import android.media.MediaRecorder.AudioSource;

import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    private AudioRecord recorder;
    private AudioTrack player;

    private MediaCodec encoder;
    private MediaCodec decoder;

    private short audioFormat = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
    private short channelConfig = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;

    private int bufferSize;
    private boolean isRecording;
    private boolean isPlaying;

    private Thread IOrecorder;

    private Thread IOudpPlayer;


    private DatagramSocket ds;
    private final int localPort = 39000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        IOrecorder = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                int read;
                byte[] buffer1 = new byte[bufferSize];

                ByteBuffer[] inputBuffers;
                ByteBuffer[] outputBuffers;

                ByteBuffer inputBuffer;
                ByteBuffer outputBuffer;

                MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufferInfo;
                int inputBufferIndex;
                int outputBufferIndex;

                byte[] outData;

                DatagramPacket packet;
                try
                {
                    encoder.start();
                    recorder.startRecording();
                    isRecording = true;
                    while (isRecording)
                    {
                        read = recorder.read(buffer1, 0, bufferSize);
                       // Log.d("AudioRecoder", read + " bytes read");
                        //------------------------

                        inputBuffers = encoder.getInputBuffers();
                        outputBuffers = encoder.getOutputBuffers();
                        inputBufferIndex = encoder.dequeueInputBuffer(-1);
                        if (inputBufferIndex >= 0)
                        {
                            inputBuffer = inputBuffers[inputBufferIndex];
                            inputBuffer.clear();

                            inputBuffer.put(buffer1);

                            encoder.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, 0, buffer1.length, 0, 0);
                        }

                        bufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
                        outputBufferIndex = encoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, 0);



                        while (outputBufferIndex >= 0)
                        {
                            outputBuffer = outputBuffers[outputBufferIndex];

                            outputBuffer.position(bufferInfo.offset);
                            outputBuffer.limit(bufferInfo.offset + bufferInfo.size);

                            outData = new byte[bufferInfo.size];
                            outputBuffer.get(outData);


                           // Log.d("AudioEncoder", outData.length + " bytes encoded");
                            //-------------
                            packet = new DatagramPacket(outData, outData.length,
                                    InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"), localPort);
                            ds.send(packet);
                            //------------

                            encoder.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferIndex, false);
                            outputBufferIndex = encoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, 0);

                        }
                        // ----------------------;

                    }
                    encoder.stop();
                    recorder.stop();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });



        IOudpPlayer = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                SocketAddress sockAddress;
                String address;

                int len = 1024;
                byte[] buffer2 = new byte[len];
                DatagramPacket packet;

                byte[] data;

                ByteBuffer[] inputBuffers;
                ByteBuffer[] outputBuffers;

                ByteBuffer inputBuffer;
                ByteBuffer outputBuffer;

                MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufferInfo;
                int inputBufferIndex;
                int outputBufferIndex;
                byte[] outData;
                try
                {
                    player.play();
                    decoder.start();
                    isPlaying = true;
                    while (isPlaying)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer2, len);
                            ds.receive(packet);

                            sockAddress = packet.getSocketAddress();
                            address = sockAddress.toString();

                         //   Log.d("UDP Receiver"," received !!! from " + address);

                            data = new byte[packet.getLength()];
                            System.arraycopy(packet.getData(), packet.getOffset(), data, 0, packet.getLength());

                           // Log.d("UDP Receiver",  data.length + " bytes received");

                            //===========
                            inputBuffers = decoder.getInputBuffers();
                            outputBuffers = decoder.getOutputBuffers();
                            inputBufferIndex = decoder.dequeueInputBuffer(-1);
                            if (inputBufferIndex >= 0)
                            {
                                inputBuffer = inputBuffers[inputBufferIndex];
                                inputBuffer.clear();

                                inputBuffer.put(data);

                                decoder.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, 0, data.length, 0, 0);
                            }

                            bufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
                            outputBufferIndex = decoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, 0);

                            while (outputBufferIndex >= 0)
                            {
                                outputBuffer = outputBuffers[outputBufferIndex];

                                outputBuffer.position(bufferInfo.offset);
                                outputBuffer.limit(bufferInfo.offset + bufferInfo.size);

                                outData = new byte[bufferInfo.size];
                                outputBuffer.get(outData);

                              //  Log.d("AudioDecoder", outData.length + " bytes decoded");

                                player.write(outData, 0, outData.length);

                                decoder.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferIndex, false);
                                outputBufferIndex = decoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, 0);

                            }

                            //===========

                        }
                        catch (IOException e)
                        {
                        }
                    }

                    decoder.stop();
                    player.stop();

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                }
            }
        });

//===========================================================
        int rate = findAudioRecord();
        if (rate != -1)
        {
            Log.v("=========media ", "ready: " + rate);
            Log.v("=========media channel ", "ready: " + channelConfig);

            boolean encoderReady = setEncoder(rate);
            Log.v("=========encoder ", "ready: " + encoderReady);
            if (encoderReady)
            {
                boolean decoderReady = setDecoder(rate);
                Log.v("=========decoder ", "ready: " + decoderReady);
                if (decoderReady)
                {
                    Log.d("=======bufferSize========", "" + bufferSize);
                    try
                    {
                        setPlayer(rate);

                        ds = new DatagramSocket(localPort);
                        IOudpPlayer.start();

                        IOrecorder.start();

                    }
                    catch (SocketException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }

            }
        }
    }


    protected void onDestroy()
    {

        recorder.release();
        player.release();
        encoder.release();
        decoder.release();

    }
/*
    protected void onResume()
    {

        // isRecording = true;
    }

    protected void onPause()
    {

        isRecording = false;
    }
*/

    private int findAudioRecord()
    {
        for (int rate : new int[]{44100})
        {
            try
            {
                Log.v("===========Attempting rate ", rate + "Hz, bits: " + audioFormat + ", channel: " + channelConfig);
                bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(rate, channelConfig, audioFormat);

                if (bufferSize != AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE)
                {
                    // check if we can instantiate and have a success
                    recorder = new AudioRecord(AudioSource.MIC, rate, channelConfig, audioFormat, bufferSize);

                    if (recorder.getState() == AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED)
                    {
                        Log.v("===========final rate ", rate + "Hz, bits: " + audioFormat + ", channel: " + channelConfig);

                        return rate;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.v("error", "" + rate);
            }

        }
        return -1;
    }

    private boolean setEncoder(int rate)
    {
        encoder = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType("audio/mp4a-latm");
        MediaFormat format = new MediaFormat();
        format.setString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME, "audio/mp4a-latm");
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT, 1);
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_SAMPLE_RATE, rate);
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 64 * 1024);//AAC-HE 64kbps
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_AAC_PROFILE, MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel.AACObjectHE);
        encoder.configure(format, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
        return true;
    }

    private boolean setDecoder(int rate)
    {
        decoder = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType("audio/mp4a-latm");
        MediaFormat format = new MediaFormat();
        format.setString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME, "audio/mp4a-latm");
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT, 1);
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_SAMPLE_RATE, rate);
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 64 * 1024);//AAC-HE 64kbps
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_AAC_PROFILE, MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel.AACObjectHE);

        decoder.configure(format, null, null, 0);

        return true;
    }

    private boolean setPlayer(int rate)
    {
        int bufferSizePlayer = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(rate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, audioFormat);
        Log.d("====buffer Size player ", String.valueOf(bufferSizePlayer));

        player= new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, rate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, audioFormat, bufferSizePlayer, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);


        if (player.getState() == AudioTrack.STATE_INITIALIZED)
        {

            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have tried the above code and it didn't work properly.I was getting lot of silence injected to the decoded output. Issue was not setting proper "csd" value to the decoder.

So if you see "silence" in log or Decoder throwing error make sure you have added the following to your media decoder format

```
int profile = 2;  //AAC LC
int freqIdx = 11;  //8KHz
int chanCfg = 1;  //Mono

ByteBuffer csd = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);
csd.put(0, (byte) (profile << 3 | freqIdx >> 1));
csd.put(1, (byte)((freqIdx & 0x01) << 7 | chanCfg << 3));
mediaFormat.setByteBuffer("csd-0", csd);
```

Comment: I tried yours. The decoded AAC data can be used for `AudioTrack.write(byte[] audioData, int offsetInBytes, int sizeInBytes)`. However the audio skips the last seconds of the audio, if `AudioTrack.write()` is invoked, the last second of audio from previous run will be played, which is odd.

Answer (score 0):

Your networking code is combining data. You got 369 bytes of compressed data, but on the receiving end you ended up with 1024 bytes. Those 1024 bytes consist of two whole and one partial frame. The two whole frames each decode to 4096 bytes again, for the total of 8192 bytes that you saw. The remaining partial frame will probably be decoded once you send sufficiently more data to the decoder, but you should generally send only whole frames to the decoder.

In addition, `MediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer()` does not only return (positive) buffer indices, but also (negative) status codes. One of the possible codes is `MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED`, which indicates that you need to call `MediaCodec.getOutputFormat()` to get the format of the audio data. You might see the codec output stereo even if the input was mono. The code you posted simply breaks out of the loop when it receives one of these status codes.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested with your souce.
there are some points.

1. Bit Rate is a natural number of K, but not computer K.
   64k = 64000, but not 64 * 1024
2. It's not recommended to write a long code that shares some variables.
   A. separate Encoder Thread and Decoder Thread into 2 independet classes.
   B. The DatagramSocket is shared by Sender and Receiver, it not good.
3. Enumerate Audio Format need more values.
      i.e. sample rates should be picked from :  8000, 11025, 22050, 44100

Answer (score 0):

D/AudioRecoder﹕ 4096 bytes read
D/AudioEncoder﹕ 360 bytes encoded
D/UDP Receiver﹕ received !!! from /127.0.0.1:39000
D/UDP Receiver﹕ 360 bytes received
D/AudioDecoder﹕ 8192 bytes decoded

> > > > > > > This is because acc decoder always decode to stereo channels,even if the encoded data is MONO. so if your encoding side is set to stereo channels, it will be like:

D/AudioRecoder﹕ 8192 bytes read
D/AudioEncoder﹕ 360 bytes encoded
D/UDP Receiver﹕ received !!! from /127.0.0.1:39000
D/UDP Receiver﹕ 360 bytes received
D/AudioDecoder﹕ 8192 bytes decoded

Comment: AFAIK, mono wav has different DB metadata vs. stereo wav.