# reduce size of audiorecord

Tags: java, android

I am using audio record to record audio and send the bytes to the remote server but I found that the bytes have a bigger size compared to the media recorder but unfortunately, I have to use audio record to deal with bytes
my question is how can I reduce its size, I heard about media codec here but I failed to use it  this is my code

```
private void startRecording() {

        recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS,
                RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, BufferElements2Rec * BytesPerElement);

        recorder.startRecording();

        isRecording = true;

        recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                writeAudioDataToFile();

            }
        }, "AudioRecorder Thread");
        recordingThread.start();
    }

    //Conversion of short to byte
    private byte[] short2byte(short[] sData) {
        int shortArrsize = sData.length;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[shortArrsize * 2];

        for (int i = 0; i < shortArrsize; ++i) {
            bytes[i * 2] = (byte) (sData[i] & 0x00FF);
            bytes[(i * 2) + 1] = (byte) (sData[i] >> 8);
            sData[i] = 0;
        }
        return bytes;
    }

    private void writeAudioDataToFile() {
        // Write the output audio in byte


        short sData[] = new short[BufferElements2Rec];



        while (isRecording) {
            // gets the voice output from microphone to byte format
            recorder.read(sData, 0, BufferElements2Rec);
          //  System.out.println("Short wirting to file" + sData.toString());
            try {
                // writes the data to file from buffer stores the voice buffer
                byte bData[] = short2byte(sData);
                String bdata2 =Base64.encodeToString(bData,Base64.DEFAULT);



            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    private void stopRecording() {
        // stops the recording activity
        if (null != recorder) {
            isRecording = false;


            recorder.stop();
            recorder.release();

            recorder = null;
            recordingThread = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: _this is my code..._ hat errors do you get? What is wrong with your code?

Comment: i dont have errors it works pretty good but i want to send the  bData[] to a server but it has a big size  i want to reduce its size

Comment: _i want to educe its size..._ What about converting t *.mp3?

Comment: how ? i already failed to convert  it

Comment: Did you tried to change the way the remote server saves the file?

Comment: note that i want to reduce the output data[] without putting it in audio file

Comment: @Estevex i want to reduce its size before sending it to the server

Comment: can i have AAc audio bytes instead of pcm ?

Comment: Sorry you can't. I was reading the AudioRecord and only accepts PCM. Someone made a similar project here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21804390/pcm-aac-encoder-pcmdecoder-in-real-time-with-correct-optimization

Comment: no way to reduce the size of the output data ?

Comment: cant i compress it ?

Comment: what about deflater and inflater ? if i used it can i reduce the size ?